# Get the position of a li in a ul

Tags: javascript, html

So i have this HTML

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="clicked(this.placeinul)"></li>
  <li onclick="clicked(this.placeinul)"></li>
  <li onclick="clicked(this.placeinul)"></li>
</ul>
```

And this javascript

```js
function clicked(placeInUl) {
  console.log(placeInUl)
}
```

So when i for example would click on the first li it would print 1 or if i clicked on the last li it would print 3. 
How would i do that?

Comment: i have tried index and indexOf but i think i am doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: plain js version

```js
function clicked(index) {
  alert(index+1);
}
```

```css
li { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick='clicked(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentElement.children, this));'>1</li>
  <li onclick='clicked(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentElement.children, this));'>2</li>
  <li onclick='clicked(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentElement.children, this));'>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's no indication that OP intended to use jQuery.

Comment: i saw that when i search on google but i dont want to use jQuery if there is a way to do it in plain javascript

Comment: @MariusE sorry, corrected